# Import module from another directory

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to import a module from another directory? If it is, how can I do this? The only way I can re-use a module from another directory is to manually copy it into my local folder and then run my elixir script via `elixir script.exs`

To add some more context, I have a folder called Utilities and another folder called Scripts. There is an elixir module called ListUtilities.ex defined in Utilities folder, which I want to reference in my script.exs. Here is a visual representation of my directory layout:

```
Utilities
   ListUtilites.ex
Scripts
   script.exs
```

In my script.exs, here is what I have at the moment:

```
import ListUtilities
```

Comment: If you are just using Elixir for small scripts, you may want to consider building an escript instead of just calling `elixir script.exs`.

Comment: What's an escript? Sorry I am currently learning elixir.

Comment: While Elixir can be used for small scripts in the way that you are calling it, it is generally better to build a fully application from it. And in your case build an [escript](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html). Keep in mind Elixir and Erlang are more or less the same thing. So on the Elixir side, you would `mix new foo` to create a new project. Then inside that project, you would run [`mix escript.build`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/master/Mix.Tasks.Escript.Build.html) and it would create a binary that you can then call.

Comment: I am going to look into this more. I am writing scripts to play around with various features of elixir as I am learning the language, but escript seems like a nice way to create scripts that can invoked just like other python/perl scripts for admin/maintenance purposes.

Answer (score 2):

> I figured out 1 way of doing this but hoping there might be a better way.
>   ...I added -pa argument (which allows you to prepend other paths to the Erlang code path).

Yep, that's the way it's done. Note that you can also use `-pz`, which appends to the end of the code path.

Or, you can use the compile command, `c()`, in iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> c(["./utils/list_utils.ex", "./scripts/cool.ex"]) 
[Cool, ListUtils]
```

Otherwise, you can create a simple mix project, put all your files in the lib directory--using any directory structure you want underneath lib--and mix will take care of `-pa`'ing all the paths of your source files.

You create a new mix project like this:

```
$ mix new my_proj
```

And, you load your project into iex with this command:

```
$ iex -S mix
```

...which will compile all your modules and make them available as `ModuleName.func_name()`.  Also, mix is smart and it only compiles the files that have changed since the last time you compiled your project.  If you find that it's a hassle to always write the module name before the function name, you can write `import ModuleName` and then you won't have to precede the function name with the module name.

====

Backtracking a bit, when you run your code like this:

```
$ elixir script.exs
```

then typically your code will look something like this:

**math.exs**:

```
defmodule Math do
  def calc({:add, x, y}) do
    x+y
  end
end

IO.inspect( Math.calc {:add, 3, 4} )
```

and your file will be saved with a name that has a `.exs` extension, where the `s` means *script*. Sometimes that's more convenient.  Other times, it's more convenient to use a file name with a `.ex` extension:

**math.ex**:

```
defmodule Math do
  def calc({:add, x, y}) do
    x+y
  end
end
```

Then you can start up iex and compile your file like this:

```
$ iex math.ex
```

Then to use your function, you write:

```
iex(1)> Math.calc({:add, 3, 4})
7

iex(2)>
```

Note how you don't have to do the `IO.inspect()` to see the return value of the function.  I find that I don't use `.exs` files much after experimenting with them a couple of times.  Typically, I write .ex files like this:

```
defmodule Math do
  def calc({:add, x, y}) do
    x+y
  end

  def go() do
    calc({:add, 3, 4})
  end
end
```

So, I create a separate function, `go()`, to test my function, which means I only have to type `Math.go` into iex which is easier than having to type `Math.calc({add, 3, 4})`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out 1 way of doing this but hoping there might be a better way.

When executing my script, I added -pa argument (which allows you to prepend other paths to the Erlang code path). So something like `elixir -pa ..\Utilities script.exs`.